# Why isn't JSP out.print() function working properly

Tags: java, html, jsp, printing

I've been working with a JSP+Java+Html, and I've encountered a problem with out.print() function, in a for cycle.
My function `getGeneAvailableTaxonomies()` returns a list of integer numbers (of type `List<Integer>`), and I want to print these numbers in an interface.

Here's my code:

```
 for(Integer i : ApplicationExtender.getApplicationExtender(application).getGeneAvailableTaxonomies()) 
        {
          out.print(String.format("<option value=\"%1$d\">%2$s</option>", i, TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)));
        }
```

The doce `%1$d` should stand for the i integer value, while `%2$s` should stand for the other parameter, the taxonomy id value as String.

But, unfortunately, this is what appears:

[image]

While I would like to see something like:

[image]

There's surely an error on my out.print() function call... but what's wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: What are %2$s & %1$d? are those variables?

Comment: Did you inspect what `TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)` returns?

Comment: @Davide: Why do you think this is about `print()` and not about `String.format()`?

Comment: @thinksteep Yes, they're related to `i` and `TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)`

Comment: @Keppil Yes, it returns a List<Integer> made of 9606, 9913, 9031

Comment: @A.H. You're right, it could be about String.format() too

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: Aren't you referring to the `ApplicationExtender.getApplicationExtender(application).getGeneAvailableTaxonomies()` now?

Comment: @all There was an error in my question: the`%2$s` parameter is a String, not an Int as a first wrote. Sorry.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it there is problem with TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)  every thing else is fine.... check what its returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the "$" in your format String. As you may know, using scriptlets is not a good way to do Java Web Development. I think that using JSTL is far better, as you won't mix Java code with markup in your JSP's.

**Edit:** The printf method is not present in **out** object as I said earlier, since it is a JspWriter and JspWriter not inherit from PrintWriter (that have printf). Sorry. So, try this (it worked for me).

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <%
                String[] strings = new String[]{ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };

                for ( int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) {
                    out.print( String.format( "<option value='%d'>%s</option>", i, strings[i] ) );
                }
            %>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use a PrintWriter as in Servlets, so this will work:

```
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <%
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( out );
                String[] strings = new String[]{ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };

                for ( int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) {
                    writer.printf( "<option value='%d'>%s</option>", i, strings[i] );
                }
            %>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: What is the return type of getOrganismFromId()?

Comment: It's a String. I've made a mistake: in the question I wrote it was an Integer. It is a String.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: Ok. I tested what I wrote and it is working. Take a look: http://ideone.com/riWD3. Can you post the markup that is being generated?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: try it now, I think it will work. Take a look in my post, I changed some things.

Comment: @davidbuzatto previous code was working like charm even out.println(String.format("<option value=\"%1$d\">%2$s</option>", 10, "Hello")); is working nice, i think there is something else which is not mentioned in question..

Comment: @blackPanther: Yes, I agree with you. Did you say that out.printf was working? If so, what container/app server are you using? I think that Tomcat doesn't implement printf in JspWriter.

Comment: @davidbuzatto my friend working out.printf("<option value=\"%1$d\">%2$s</option>", 10, "Hello");  i am using tomcat 7

Comment: @davidbuzatto the problem is with this TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i) we dont know what its return ... if you want i can post images(working)

Comment: i tried it within servlet yup jspwriter doesn't implement printf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14293/discussion-between-davidbuzatto-and-blackpanther)

Answer (score 0):

try this as much i have understood :

```
        String option = "<option value=\""+d+"\">"+s+"</option>";    
        out.print(option);
```

using `String.format`

```
out.print(String.format("<option value=\"%d\">%s</option>", i, TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)));
```

**Updated**
as you have mentioned in comments that `TaxonID.getOrganismFromId(i)` is returning `int` so the there is only one change in your original code `%2$s` to `%2$d` thats it...

```
out.print(String.format("<option value=\"%1$d\">%2$d</option>", i, TaxonId.getOrganismFromId(i)));
```

Comment: @gustafc: I thought the same thing.

Comment: look at this you will come to know ..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: You mean he'd like his users to see text like *%3Coption%20value%3D%221000%22%3E1000%3C%2Foption%3E* instead of a dropdown?

Comment: no the browser will decode it automatically and then there will be a dropdown with values..

Comment: @blackPanther: The browser _would_ decode it when this data is received in an _URL_ of the request but not inside the HTML. Hence the name _URL_Encoder.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it its working fine i have checked it ...., may be there is some other mistake you are doing

Comment: @DavideChicco.it even i have tried this out.println(String.format("<option value=\"%1$d\">%2$s</option>", 10, "Hello"));  works great

Answer (score 0):

Your `print`/`format` code seems OK when I run it on http://ideone.com/u8fDT. You probably just need to have the JSP recompiled (should probably happen automatically but may sometimes require server restart).

Also, mixing HTML and Java code like this is a pretty painful way to work. JSTL or a templating system like FreeMarker would make your life easier.